# How to send login information while PHP copy

Tags: php

```
$url1 = 'www.somewebsite.com/somefile.ext';

if (@copy($url1, "somefolder/filename.ext"))
{
echo 'File 1 saved.';
}
```

This code works well when I tried to copy a file without any login permissions. But when I tried to copy a file with login permission, the file is not get copied. Is there anyway to send login information too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way is to encode login info in the URL, before the server.  For example:

```
http://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt
```

Remember to think about security.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the login is a basic HTTP one, you can use [`stream_context_create`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to pass your details:

```php
$cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s', 
      base64_encode($username . ":" . $password) );

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => $cred
    )
));

$url1 = 'www.somewebsite.com/somefile.ext';

if (@copy($url1, "somefolder/filename.ext", $context))
{
    echo 'File 1 saved.';
}
```